# Use operators 'like` or 'greater than' in Knex query with object syntax

Tags: bookshelf.js, knex.js

I'm using JSON objects to build Knex queries like this:

`{where: {id: '5'}`

How can I use the same query format (object syntax) with operators like `like` or `greater than` ?

Comment: Leaving a comment for those like me who are looking for a way to use greater than / less than using Bookshelf or Knex without the object syntax: `knex('users').where('votes', '>', 100)` or `BookshelfModel.query('where', 'votes', '>', 100)` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. Looking at [the relevant source code of the query builder](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/src/query/builder.js#L263), it looks like:

```js
_objectWhere(obj) {
  const boolVal = this._bool();
  const notVal = this._not() ? 'Not' : '';
  for (const key in obj) {
    this[boolVal + 'Where' + notVal](key, obj[key]);
  }
  return this;
}
```

Which basically calls the appropiate `Where` function with just two parameters (thus no operator, which means `=`)

Answer (score 13):

You can use **where/andWhere**. The code below shows an update that only happens if the **user_id = userId** and **book_reference = bookName** and if **result < res**.

```
knex('user_books')
    .where({
      user_id: userId,
      book_reference: bookName
    })
    .andWhere('result', '<', res)
    .update({
      'updated_at': bookshelf.knex.raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
      'text_done': true,
    })
```